# How to smooth the face after boolean modifier applied?

Tags: modifiers, shaders, faces

The face is not smooth out after I applied boolean modifier and after shade smooth.

[image: The face is not smooth after boolean]

[image: The wireframe]

Comment: Try the subdivision surface modifier

Answer (score 1):

The ngons create artifacts, try this solution (quads only):

[image]